# passing hashtags as parameters to twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, parameters, sanitize, hashtag

I have the following tweet:

```
var tweet = "I might actually do a 5K: http://t.co/tXQIYlUt #zombies #running"
```

And I would like to pass this to the twitter api using js

```
$('.my_div').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text='+ tweet +'%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>')
```

My JS creates this: `https://twitter.com/share?text=I%20might%20actually%20do%20a%205K:%20http://t.co/tXQIYlUt%20#zombies #running&via=JustinZollars&url=`

which renders this way at twitter.com:

> I might actually do a 5K: http://t.co/tXQIYlUt  http://mydomain.com/

notice it cut out my hash tags. how can I sanitize my url?

Resources:

1. [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent()` your GET param (the `tweet` variable). Also, don't encode the GET params that you do want to have special meaning (the `&` and `=`).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUXDA/).